# Why, if in the debug mode you would pass through the line AudioSource.Play, playback does not start immediately after the line is executed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-components

Why, if in the debug mode you would pass through the line AudioSource.Play(); playback does not start immediately after the line is executed?

```
public AudioSource inactiveMusic;

void Start()
{
    inactiveMusic.Play();
}
```

But if the line AudioSource.Play() is written twice, then playback will start immediately after the execution of the second line:

```
public AudioSource inactiveMusic;

void Start()
{
    inactiveMusic.Play();
    inactiveMusic.Play();
}
```

Why the hell it is working like that? What's the logic?